# Rest API logging in websphere clustured environment

Tags: java, logging, websphere, cluster-computing, rest

I have few rest services bundled to an ear and deployed to Websphere application server in PROD clustered environment(16 Websphere app server instances). IHS webserver instances are serving the incoming requests to above app servers.

I need to capture request/response details and few logs during processing of the request. In PROD the debug log is by default disabled, I need a way to enable debug logs in all app servers without any deployments.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe NCSA logging is what you are looking for
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/9.0.5?topic=application-enabling-access-logging